# Rails 5 custom method resource previous/next in controller or model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, will-paginate, acts-as-taggable-on

I have a quiz application that uses `acts_as_taggable` and `will_paginate` to show one item at a time.

I created a model called **MultipleChoiceQuestion** (MCQ). Each MCQ has associated things with it, along with tags.

What I want to do is create a variety of different custom methods in the controller that will only collect questions that have certain tags attributed to the MCQ.

I want to then let the user see one question at a time with the custom method defined tags.

So, for example:

**The controller:**

```
def pharmas1
    @sem1_pharma_mcq = MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["pharmacology", "sem1"], :match_all => true).all.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 1)
end
```

**The view**

```
<% @sem1_pharma_mcq.each do |sem1_pharma_mcq| %>

<hr>
<%= sem1_pharma_mcq.question %> <Br>

<%= sem1_pharma_mcq.answer_one %>
<%= sem1_pharma_mcq.answer_two %>
<%= sem1_pharma_mcq.answer_three %>
<%= sem1_pharma_mcq.answer_four %>
<%= sem1_pharma_mcq.answer_correct %>

<%= sem1_pharma_mcq.answer_explanation %>
<%= sem1_pharma_mcq.tag_list %>

<hr>
<%= link_to "Next Question →", @sem1_pharma_mcq.next, :class => 'button next-question' %>

<%= will_paginate @sem1_pharma_mcq %>
<% end %>
```

**The model:**

```
 acts_as_taggable

def next
  MultipleChoiceQuestion.tagged_with(["sem1", "pharmacology"], :match_all => true).order(id: :asc).limit(1).first
end


def prev
  MultipleChoiceQuestion.where("id < ?", id).order(id: :desc).limit(1).first
end
```

The routes.rb

```
  resources :multiple_choice_questions, path: 'mcqs' do
    get 'pharmas1', :on => :collection
  end
```

I'm trying to accomplish two things:

1. Allow the user to view one question at a time with the rails "show" action/method, rather than using will_paginate to show one question at a time on the index.

I don't know how to go about this, and my functionality is working only through a custom gem? How can I show custom actions once per page in the show view template?

2. Allow the user to go previous/next on this show action/method but making sure that only questions of a certain tag are being applied.

The error here is: undefined method `next' for # when I try load the custom method named "pharmas1" -- which is defined in the multiple_choice_questions_controller.rb file

Comment: Did you have a look at: https://github.com/schneems/wicked ?

Comment: @Robert I don't think this would work for anything that has dozens if not hundreds of steps?

Comment: I don't see why it would not work